# need to replace the data that you enter into a csv file

Tags: java, arrays, csv, try-catch

Im trying to making a program that shows the criterias and students marks in console from csv file. I figured the reach the column but i need to reach also the row so  when the teacher wants to enter a mark program should show the criterias in order and it should replace the marks that teacher entered in the csv file. Anyone can help me how to replace the marks inside the csv file ?  It looks like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iixhu.png)

I did this for the column

```java
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("project.csv"));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] cols = line.split(",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a library for CSV parsing and printing. Apache Commons CSV would be a good choice. You can find the guide here: https://www.baeldung.com/apache-commons-csv